How to format original text and all connected celsl take on same formatting
I'm not too sure how to correctly word this, but basically i have a table of different country names, and then loads of mini tables of people who have different combination of those countries. The way i created this for each person is just doing a simple formula of ={cell of country name}.
All i want to do is to be able to format the original country name i.e. ctrl + 5 to do a strikethrough, and if that country name is in the mini tables, they too take on the formatting. Maybe add a fill colour too. There is a screengrab below, where the original country name i've formatted and wanted every cell that has that country to take on the same text format


Unless you want to edit conditional formatting everytime you want to change the format of a cell, you will probably need VBA with an event listener to do this.

Ah ive worked out how to do it with conditional formatting thank you

In that case @JDCov87 you can answer your own question with your solution, so people know it's solved.
